# Auto Response Event Trigger Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make an auto responder that gives out random responses when specific words are typed. But it's not triggering the responses at all. Here is my event trigger. Maybe someone can figure out what is broken in it?

````
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx, *, message):
        msg = ctx.message
        guild = ctx.guild
        content = message.content
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        bad_list = [
            "swear 1",
            "swear 1",
            "swear 3"]
        s_responses = [
            "response 1",
            "response 2",
            "response 3"]
        joke_list = [
            "joke 1",
            "joke 2",
            "joke 3"]
        joke_response = random.choice(joke_list)
        j_response = str(f"""```css\n{joke_response}```""")
        s_response = str(f"""```css\n{s_responses}```""")
        get_help = str("""```css\nI can't help you with this problem!```""")
        bot_web = str("""```css\nhttps:\\newhorizon-development.netlify.app\```""")
        bns_web = str("""```css\nhttps:\\www.blandandsoul.com\```""")
        if any(content.startswitch("telljoke")):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=j_response, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(eembed=embed)
        if any(content.startswith(word) for word in bad_list):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=s_response, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        if any(content.startswith("gethelp")):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=get_help, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        if any(content.startswith("botwebsite")):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=bot_web, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        if any(content.startswith("bnsweb")):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=bns_web, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
````

I'm using discord.py rewrite if it helps...

--EDIT--

Working fix provided by Smoliarick. Thank you so much for the help. Editing this into the main post for anyone who wants to use it =).

````py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            msg = message
            guild = message.guild
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            bad_list = ["SWEAR",
                        "SWEAR",
                        "SWEAR"]
            responses = ["RESPONSE",
                         "RESPONSE",
                         "RESPONSE"]
            for bad_word in bad_list:
                if bad_word in message.content:
                    response = random.choice(responses)
                    c_r = str(f"""```css\n{response}```""")
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=c_r, inline=False)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    return
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename second `on_message` function and add `name='on_message'` in `@commands.Cog.listener()` for renamed function:

```py
class ExampleBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            msg = message
            guild = message.guild
            content = message.content
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            bad_list = [
                "swear 1",
                "swear 1",
                "swear 3"]
            responses = [
                "response 1",
                "response 2",
                "response 3"]
            # check bad words
            for bad_word in bad_list:
                if bad_word in message.content:
                    return            

            response = random.choice(responses)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name,
                                icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=response, inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener(name='on_message')
    async def on_message_second(self, message):
        print("Hello")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(ExampleBot(client))

setup(client)
```

Try this:

````py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            msg = message
            guild = message.guild
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            bad_list = ["fuck",
                        "bitch",
                        "slut",
                        "dick",
                        "ass",
                        "dike",
                        "cunt",
                        "pussy",
                        "nigger",
                        "kkk",
                        "negro",
                        "cracka",
                        "jew",
                        "honkie"]
            responses = ["I hope you didn't kiss your mother with that mouth....",
                         ".....some people these days..... need to good switch to the [REDACTED]",
                         "Who taught you to use such filthy language?!?",
                         "Oh yes, talk dirty to me....",
                         "You FILTHY CASUAL! You need to learn better swears!",
                         "You're choice in words is reassuring. I know that you will never be anything now.",
                         "FUCK! Another one slipped through! GRAB THE RAID!",
                         "SHIT! SHIT! WE GOT ONE! WE FINALLY GOT ONE! GET THE HAMMER!"]
            for bad_word in bad_list:
                if bad_word in message.content:
                    response = random.choice(responses)
                    c_r = str(f"""```css\n{response}```""")
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=c_r, inline=False)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    return
````

Comment: ok so as it stands this isn't responding at all either. no errors but no response either. I'll attach the updated i have below as well since I removed a large portion of it to make up for some of the embeds being far to large. `some of it got moved into commands rather than autorepsonses due to that issue`

Comment: Yo I goofed. It's responding to everything BUT the words in the `bad_list`. can you still help with this?

Comment: It's responding to the bot again..... even with the flag there...

Comment: Do you add `if not message.author.bot:` in your function? You need to add it in the first and second functions which call `on_message`.

Comment: oof it's not in the second one that might be the issue....;

Comment: nope still spamming no stop now. also i got the css to work btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216769/discussion-between-nimbi-and-smoliarick).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I have so far:

--EDIT--

Accidentally left out the random.choice part...

````
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        msg = message
        guild = message.guild
        content = message.content
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        bad_list = [
            "swear 1",
            "swear 2",
            "swear 3"      
        ]
        responses = [
            "response 1",
            "response 2",
            "response 3" 
        ]
        if any(content.startswith(word) for word in bad_list):
            return
        c_response = str(f"""```css\n{responses}```""")
        response = random.choice(c_response)
        if any(content.startswith(word) for word in bad_list):
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=response, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
````

Some of the jokes were too big for the embeds so I changed those to a working madlib command and now all that is left of the original code is what I have above.

However it still isn't responding. so pretty much the same issue I had before.

I am running it from inside a cog which is why I have `self.client` instead of `client`.

Comment: Maybe you don't add cog in client? Check my solution, I updated my code, may be it help you. It work for me.

Comment: The cog is added. It's running inside my events cog and the other events all work flawlessly. Would having multiple `on_message` effect it at all? Because I have a separate `on_message` event for my levels handler. So this one is using it's own `on_message` event.

Comment: I'm also seeing another thing wrong in your screenshot. you'r si showing the entire list of responses rather than picking one at random.

Comment: Yes, I check it. I have one function `on_message` with  `@client.event` and `on_message` in Cog. When I send a message, at first call `on_message` with `@client.event` and then call `on_message` in Cog.

Comment: Could you show your code with class and methods in it without realization (with `pass` in the body of the methods)?

Comment: Ah i messed up in the second version then. it's suppose to be random choice response. and yours is working despite mine not ... this is getting confusing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216764/discussion-between-nimbi-and-smoliarick).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full code... I won't be ommitting the swears and responses this time because my `Events.py` file is huge..

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
import json
import datetime
import random
from random import randint




epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
time_diff = round((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds())


def load_counters():
    with open('./data/counters.json', 'r') as f:
        counters = json.load(f)
    return counters


def save_counters(counters):
    with open('./data/counters.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(counters, f, indent=4)

class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f"r?help | in {len(self.client.guilds)} servers", type=ActivityType.playing))
        print(" ")
        print("License")
        print(" ")
        print("Copyright (c) Joshua Lewis")
        print(" ")
        print("Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy")
        print("of this software and associated documentation files (the Software), to deal")
        print("in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights")
        print("to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell")
        print("copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is")
        print("furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:")
        print(" ")
        print("The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all")
        print("copies or substantial portions of the Software.")
        print(" ")
        print("THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED AS IS, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR")
        print("IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,")
        print("FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE")
        print("AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER")
        print("LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,")
        print("OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE")
        print("SOFTWARE.")
        print("Connecting to Discord API")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print(f"Logged in as : {self.client.user.name}#{self.client.user.discriminator}")
        print("Collecting list of connected guilds")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print("Connected Guilds:")
        print(f"{self.client.guilds}")

    def check_all_message(check_for, message):
        if check_for in message.content:
            return True
        elif check_for in message.embed:
            return True

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        guild = message.author.guild
        author = message.author
        ch = message.channel
        content = message.content
        orange = discord.Color.dark_orange()
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":
                msg_del = str(f"""```css\n{content}```""")
                aut_name = str(f"""```css\n{author.name}```""")
                ch_name = str(f"""```css\n{ch.name}```""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=orange, timestamp=message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Message Deleted", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Message", value=msg_del, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Message Author", value=aut_name, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Channel", value=ch_name, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=author.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(f'message: {content} by {author.name} was deleted in {ch.name}')



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, ctx, member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        msg = ctx.message
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        user_join = str(f"""```css\n{member.name} has entered {guild.name}.```""")
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name=f"{self.client.user.name} Saotomi", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Use Joined", value=user_join, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, ctx, member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        msg = ctx.message
        red = discord.Color.dark_red()
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":
                user_left = str(f"""```css\n{member.name} has left {guild.name}""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=red, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name=f"{self.client.user.name} Saotomi", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="User Left", value=user_left, inline=False)
                embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        msg = message
        guild = message.guild
        content = message.content
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        bad_list = ["fuck",
                    "bitch",
                    "slut",
                    "dick",
                    "ass",
                    "dike",
                    "cunt",
                    "pussy",
                    "nigger",
                    "kkk",
                    "negro",
                    "cracka",
                    "jew",
                    "honkey"]
        responses = ["I hope you didn't kiss your mother with that mouth....",
                     ".....some people these days..... need to good switch to the [REDACTED]",
                     "Who taught you to use such filthy language?!?",
                     "Oh yes, talk dirty to me....",
                     "You FILTHY CASUAL! You need to learn better swears!",
                     "You're choice in words is reassuring. I know that you will never be anything now.",
                     "FUCK! Another one slipped through! GRAB THE RAID!",
                     "SHIT! SHIT! WE GOT ONE! WE FINALLY GOT ONE! GET THE HAMMER!"]
        if any(content.startswith(word) for word in bad_list):
            return
        response = random.choice(responses)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name,
                         icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=response, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        author = ctx.author
        content = ctx.content
        """Logs a user's xp to json file for use with the levels and currency system. If no user data is present, new user data is created."""
        if content.startswith('B.') is not True:

            if guild != None:

                F = open("./data/levels.json")

                level = json.load(F)

                user_time = round((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds())

                if str(f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}") not in level:
                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"] = {}
                    print(f"A log has been created for {guild.name}:{guild.id}")

                if str(f"{author.name}:{author.id}") not in level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"]:
                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"] = {"level": "1", "xp": "0", "NT": f"0", "multi": f"1", "txp": f"0", "starttime": f"{user_time}"}

                    print(f"A log entry has been created for {author.name}:{author.id} in {guild.name}:{guild.id}")

                if user_time - int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["NT"]) >= 60:
                    RNum = randint(1, 5)
                    MP = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["multi"])
                    XP = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["xp"]) + (RNum * MP)
                    TXP = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["txp"]) + (RNum * MP)
                    LVL = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["level"])

                    if XP >= 20 * LVL ** 2:
                        XP = XP % (20 * LVL ** 2)
                        LVL += 1

                        F1 = open("./data/currency.json")
                        mon = json.load(F1)

                        if str(f"{author.name}:{author.id}") not in mon:
                            mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"] = {"money": "0", "hist": "0", "multimon": "1"}

                        RNum1 = randint(1, 25)
                        MM = int(mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["multimon"])
                        Money = int(mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["money"]) + round(RNum1 * (LVL + 1) * MM)
                        HMoney = int(mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["hist"]) + round(RNum1 * (LVL + 1) * MM)

                        F1.close()

                        mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["money"] = f"{Money}"
                        mon[f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["hist"] = f"{HMoney}"
                        level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"level"] = f"{LVL}"
                        level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"xp"] = f"{XP}"

                        with open("./data/currency.json", "w") as F1w:
                            json.dump(mon, F1w, indent=4)

                        print(f"{author.name}\nXP: {XP}\nLevel: {LVL}")

                    XP = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["xp"])

                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"multi"] = f"{MP}"
                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"xp"] = f"{XP}"
                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"txp"] = f"{TXP}"
                    level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"][f"NT"] = f"{user_time}"

                    ttime = (user_time) - round(int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["starttime"]))

                    F.close()

                    with open("./data/levels.json", "w") as Fw:
                        json.dump(level, Fw, indent=4)

                    anlvl = int(level[f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}"][f"{author.name}:{author.id}"]["level"])
                    ttimeday = int(int(ttime) / 86400)
                    ttimehour = int((int(ttime) % 86400) / 3600)
                    ttimemin = int(((int(ttime) % 86400) % 3600) / 60)
                    if ttimeday == int(1):
                        tday = ""
                    else:
                        tday = "s"
                    if ttimehour == int(1):
                        thour = ""
                    else:
                        thour = "s"
                    if ttimemin == int(1):
                        tmin = ""
                    else:
                        tmin = "s"
                    msgtt = f"{ttimeday} day{tday}, {ttimehour} hour{thour}, and {ttimemin} minute{tmin}"
                    if anlvl in [10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 300]:
                        print(f"CONGRATS! {author.mention} has made it to level {anlvl} in just {msgtt}!")



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Events(client))
````

and this is the function that calls the cogs from the `bot.py` file:

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok now it just did this....

[image]

No idea what is happening now...

--EDIT--

and error message too:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshu\PycharmProjects\Discord_Bots\Ranma\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joshu\PycharmProjects\Discord_Bots\Ranma\ranma\cogs\Events.py", line 159, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\Joshu\PycharmProjects\Discord_Bots\Ranma\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 856, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed, nonce=nonce)
  File "C:\Users\Joshu\PycharmProjects\Discord_Bots\Ranma\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
```

Comment: `response = random.choice(responses)` not `response = random.choice(c_response)`. You iterated for string not list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
import json
import datetime
import random

epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
time_diff = round((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds())



def load_counters():
    with open('./data/counters.json', 'r') as f:
        counters = json.load(f)
    return counters


def save_counters(counters):
    with open('./data/counters.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(counters, f, indent=4)

class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f"r?help | in {len(self.client.guilds)} servers", type=ActivityType.playing))
        print(" ")
        print("License")
        print(" ")
        print("Copyright (c) Joshua Lewis")
        print(" ")
        print("Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy")
        print("of this software and associated documentation files (the Software), to deal")
        print("in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights")
        print("to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell")
        print("copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is")
        print("furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:")
        print(" ")
        print("The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all")
        print("copies or substantial portions of the Software.")
        print(" ")
        print("THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED AS IS, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR")
        print("IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,")
        print("FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE")
        print("AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER")
        print("LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,")
        print("OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE")
        print("SOFTWARE.")
        print("Connecting to Discord API")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print(f"Logged in as : {self.client.user.name}#{self.client.user.discriminator}")
        print("Collecting list of connected guilds")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print("Connected Guilds:")
        print(f"{self.client.guilds}")

    def check_all_message(check_for, message):
        if check_for in message.content:
            return True
        elif check_for in message.embed:
            return True

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            guild = message.author.guild
            author = message.author
            ch = message.channel
            content = message.content
            orange = discord.Color.dark_orange()
            for channel in guild.channels:
                if str(channel.name) == "log":
                    msg_del = str(f"""```css\n{content}```""")
                    aut_name = str(f"""```css\n{author.name}```""")
                    ch_name = str(f"""```css\n{ch.name}```""")
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=orange, timestamp=message.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name="Message Deleted", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name=f"Message", value=msg_del, inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name=f"Message Author", value=aut_name, inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name=f"Channel", value=ch_name, inline=False)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=author.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)
                    print(f'message: {content} by {author.name} was deleted in {ch.name}')



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, ctx, member):
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            guild = ctx.guild
            msg = ctx.message
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            user_join = str(f"""```css\n{member.name} has entered {guild.name}.```""")
            for channel in guild.channels:
                if str(channel.name) == "log":
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name=f"{self.client.user.name} Saotomi", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="Use Joined", value=user_join, inline=False)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, ctx, member):
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            guild = ctx.guild
            msg = ctx.message
            red = discord.Color.dark_red()
            for channel in guild.channels:
                if str(channel.name) == "log":
                    user_left = str(f"""```css\n{member.name} has left {guild.name}""")
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=red, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name=f"{self.client.user.name} Saotomi", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="User Left", value=user_left, inline=False)
                    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            msg = message
            guild = message.guild
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            bad_list = ["fuck",
                        "bitch",
                        "slut",
                        "dick",
                        "ass",
                        "dike",
                        "cunt",
                        "pussy",
                        "nigger",
                        "kkk",
                        "negro",
                        "cracka",
                        "jew",
                        "honkie"]
            responses = ["I hope you didn't kiss your mother with that mouth....",
                         ".....some people these days..... need to good switch to the [REDACTED]",
                         "Who taught you to use such filthy language?!?",
                         "Oh yes, talk dirty to me....",
                         "You FILTHY CASUAL! You need to learn better swears!",
                         "You're choice in words is reassuring. I know that you will never be anything now.",
                         "FUCK! Another one slipped through! GRAB THE RAID!",
                         "SHIT! SHIT! WE GOT ONE! WE FINALLY GOT ONE! GET THE HAMMER!"]
            for bad_word in bad_list:
                if bad_word in message.content:
                    return
                response = random.choice(responses)
                c_r = str(f"""```css\n{response}```""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, timestamp=msg.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="⚠", value=c_r, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Events(client))
````

this one keeps spamming the responses endlessly whenever i run a command.